# Show why given set is not a frame

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I am rather new to this material and an explanation of what is happening would be greatly appreciated.  At first glance, it seems like the sum of squares is bounded at both ends but I guess I'm looking at it completely wrong.  The question is as follows:

Consider the set $\Phi = \{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, ...\} \subset \ell^2 (\Bbb Z_+)$ with

$\varphi_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0, ...)$

$\varphi_2 = (0, 1/2, 0, 0)$

$\varphi_3 = (0, 0, 1/4, 0, ...)$

...

Why is $\Phi$ not a frame for $\ell^2 (\Bbb Z_+)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your set to be a frame, you need
$$
\alpha\,\|v\|^2\leq\sum_k|\langle \varphi_k,v\rangle|^2\leq\beta\|v\|^2
$$
for **every** vector $v$ and certain fixed constants $\alpha,\beta>0$.

Now if you take $v=\varphi_j$ for some integer $j$, 
then
$$
\sum_k|\langle \varphi_k,\varphi_j\rangle|^2=|\langle\varphi_j,\varphi_j\rangle|^2=(2^{-j+1})^4=2^{-4j+4}.
$$
If the set was a frame, we would have some constant $\alpha>0$ such that
$$
2^{-4j+4}=\sum_k|\langle \varphi_k,\varphi_j\rangle|^2\geq\alpha\|\varphi_j\|^2=\alpha\,2^{-2j+2}.
$$
The inequality above is $2^{-2j}\geq\alpha/4$. This fails for $j$ big enough.